# Remove Single Backslash String R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I've looked at some of the answers to questions about removing a special character such as "\" from text string but they're not resolving the issue I'm having removing all backslashes.

I've tried gsub and stringr's str_replace but neither has worked.

str_remove(urls, "\")

gsub("\","",urls)

Removing or trimming all backslashes in the text string.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash

Comment: In R as with many (most?) languages, the backslash is used to escape special characters. In order to include the literal backslash, it must be escaped. This is complicated in R because R only allows some specific special characters to use a single-backslash (e.g., `\n`, `\r`, `\t`), and any other use of the backslash must escape itself explicitly ... and sometimes this means escaping the escaped backslash (frustrating as that might sound). So try `str_remove(urls, '\\\\')` and `gsub("\\\\","",urls)`.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks very much.