# r - Remove single backslash

Tags: r, regex

I have a string with backslash and I want to remove them.

```
test = "m \"#\""
```

Have tried the following but none works :

```
gsub( "\\\\", "", test )
gsub( "\\\\", "", test, fixed = T )
gsub( "\\", "", test )
gsub( "\\", "", test, fixed = T )
```

Have looked into similar questions but none of the solutions work.

[Replace single backslash in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/replace-single-backslash-in-r)
[Remove Single Backslash String R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440935/remove-single-backslash-string-r)

**Edit :** Actually this text is going to be passed in system() function to run a mosquitto client. User will give various parameters as input and the command will be created up on the fly.

The full command looks like this : `mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -q 0 -k 60 -t \"#\"`

However it is expected to be like this : `mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -q 0 -k 60 -t "#"`

Otherwise `system()` does not take it. Hence is the requirement to remove the backslaches.

The parameters `0` and `60` and `#` are supplied by user. Hence using paste0() to make this string. After the string is created the backslashes comes up.

The string given in text here is to create a reproducible and short example here.

Comment: No idea about R but is your input string actually valid using multiple double quotes inside? Aren't the backslashes there for a reason and escape the quotes inside the string? I seen a post stating `cat(test)` would print your value without the escape characters.

Comment: It is actually created by appending strings dynamically using paste0(). Hence it looks like this.

Comment: cat() just escapes those characters and print the unescaped version as expected. That don't help much.

Comment: Well, It was just an suggestion. For me, not knowing much about R it just looks like you would corrupt your string removing those backslashes. Maybe that's why R won't let you? Maybe [this](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/string-manipulation-with-stringr-in-r/string-basics?ex=2) is helpfull and you should change the outer double quotes to single quotes? Good luck anyways =)

Comment: @JvdV is correct - you can't remove the backslashes because they don't exist in your data - they're there to escape the quotes and are an artefact of printing.  You can see that using `nchar(test)` returns `5` not `7`.

Comment: Your third character is \" it isn't a \.

Comment: Have added the main context in question as Edit for better clarification of the source of single backslash in R.

Comment: Please reopen the question. I have clearly mentioned in the question itself that none of the previous solutions given in other links work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no backslash in your string

```
grepl("\\", test, fixed = TRUE)
# FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think JvdV is right, I don't think the string `"m "#""` can exist within R without the backslashes. The backslash makes " and # characters rather than acting as open/close quotation marks and a comment mark respectively.
If you had `""""` you'd get an error as you have a set of quotation marks within another set which is not possible. The same might occur for `"m "#""`. However if you input `"m "#""` the hash acts a comment symbol, making everything after it a comment and you get `"m "`. You need backslashes to make " not a quotation mark but a character, and # not a comment symbol but a character.